# How to pass image source as Property in React JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How do I pass an image source as property (props) to  a child class?

Comment: You should first try yourself and then ask if you get stuck - and show your attempt (code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you .

```
<ClidClass imageSrc={'YOUR IMAGE SRC'} />
```

On child class

```
componentDidMount(){
 let imgSrc= this.props.imageSrc

}
```

If you still any confusion you may ask .

Comment: Okay. I will try in a code,and ask if I don't understand. Meanwhile,please help me understand the use of bind()